# Git pull origin master failing

Tags: git

I'm trying to run

```
git pull origin master
```

on my production server, however it is failing with the following.

```
From ssh://bitbucket.org/ala_arab/admnet
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging db/schema.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in db/schema.rb
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

This may be because I ran rake db:migrate on my development server, and it changed the schema file in a different direction than on the production server. How do I fix this on my production server? I need to pull my changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the file you'll see git's conflict markers: `<<<`, `===`, and `>>>` These indicate the position(s) of the conflict(s). You'll need to edit the file to resolve these conflicts, then add and commit the file.

A better approach is to resolve the conflict somewhere other than on your production server. Do `git reset --hard HEAD` or `git merge --abort` (thanks, MirMasej) to restore the previous state of master. At the moment, your application may well be broken in production.

Comment: running git reset --hard HEAD on my development server is not doing anything. It just reverts to the latest commit, which is ahead of the production server. I do see those git conflict markers in the schema file on the production server. But I don't think I should be editing the schema file manually, I don't want to lose data and it does not seem the right way to handle it.

Comment: You were advised to revert changes on **production** server to restore it to functioning state. You can use `git merge --abort` for that too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do it the other way around.

- abort merge on production server
- pull the changes from prod to dev
- merge
- check if everything works fine
- pull the changes on prod.